# How to declare pre-existing variable in a TypeScript script?

Tags: typescript

I have a script which will run with a pre-defined binding, say `response`.

I have a TS interface which informs my code of what I can do with `response`.

How can I let TypeScript know that this pre-defined variable exists?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
import { HttpResponse } from './response';

// FIXME this binding already exists in the context of this script
let response: HttpResponse

// use response with type-checking
console.log(response.statusCode);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [global scope augmentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules) to make the code in the module aware that `response` is defined somewhere in the global scope:

```
import { HttpResponse } from './response';

declare global {
    let response: HttpResponse;
}
```